# Add row span when click column inside checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table like

[image]

This table has a checkbox in the first column. When I click checkbox the table will look like below.

[image: image after selecting checkbox]

The following code to add rowspan to the table column but the content is not changing.

```
 var previous = null, cellToExtend = null, rowspan = 1;
             $j(".positions-table").find("td:nth-child(3)").each(function(index, e){

                var jthis = $j(this), content = jthis.text();
                if (previous != null && $j.inArray(index, self.firstColumnBrakes) === -1) {
                    // hide the row instead of remove(), so the DOM index won't "move" inside loop.
                    jthis.addClass('hidden');
                    cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", (rowspan = rowspan+1));

                }else{
                    // store row breaks only for the first column:
                    if(i === 1) self.firstColumnBrakes.push(index);
                    cellToExtend = jthis;
                    previous = content;
                }
             });
```

Comment: What is `cellToExtend` ?

Comment: its a variable to store the currently selected row

Comment: I guess issue is at `if(i === 1)`. Shouldn't it be `if(index === 1)`?

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: What is someone unchecked the checkbox ? what is the behaviour in this case ?